# Group a specific script in the Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I use a script from the excellent plugin `geometric_attributes` for use it in a stand-alone process (his function named `Centerlines`). It works like a charm, good.

But I cannot move it to my own custom group in the *Processing Toolbox*, and I can not rename it.

In the official plugin, it is well stored in the group of the plugin, and in a specific sub-group, and well named. But after I changed the `group` and `groupId` section, it remains named *model* and below the *Scripts* tab, I am jealous!

When we have a lot a Python scripts, plugins... in the *Processing Toolbox*, even if all works, it is nice to be able to name and store them in a consistent way, so I am a little sad about that.

Please, have you an idea?

I can post the full code of my custom `Centerlines` script, but it is a bit long, and not a lot of change with the official version. But tell me if necessary.

Comment: Can't you just copy the code and paste it into another py file in your desired location?

Comment: Best check the actual files in your `YOURPROFILE/processing/scripts/` to make sure you didn't edit some copy somewhere else.